# Sync current selected item between radio and select

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Short version**
I've two forms. One with Radio-Buttons, one with Dropdowns (select).
Both have the same structure. If e.g the value of the Radio-Button changes, the dropdown-counterpart should change to the same value.

Limitations:
The ID and the `name` attribute of each radio and select are random. The backend will generate some random values. So i'm not able to use them. Messy, I know. But I can't change that.
The only thing that won't change is the CSS-class.

Here is what I got already:
I gave every select and every *single* radio button a class which clearify the value:

```
// All Mobile Selects
var $mobRechnung = $mobile.find('.js-notification-set--rechnung'),
    $mobJahr = $mobile.find('.js-notification-set--jahr'),
    $mobMonat = $mobile.find('.js-notification-set--monat'),
    $mobErinnerung = $mobile.find('.js-notification-set--erinnerung');

// All Desktop Radios
var $deskRechnungBrief = $desktop.find('js-notification-set--rechnung-brief'),
    $deskRechnungMail = $desktop.find('js-notification-set--rechnung-mail'),

    $deskJahrBrief = $desktop.find('js-notification-set--jahr-brief'),
    $deskJahrMail = $desktop.find('js-notification-set--jahr-mail'),
    $deskJahrNo = $desktop.find('js-notification-set--jahr-no'),

    $deskMonatMail = $desktop.find('js-notification-set--monat-mail'),
    $deskMonatSMS = $desktop.find('js-notification-set--monat-sms'),
    $deskMonatNo = $desktop.find('js-notification-set--monat-no'),

    $deskErinnerungMail = $desktop.find('js-notification-set--erinnerung-mail'),
    $deskErinnerungSMS = $desktop.find('js-notification-set--erinnerung-sms'),
    $deskErinnerungNo = $desktop.find('js-notification-set--erinnerung-no');
```

As you see, I can't combine the radio buttons since I'm unable to use their `name`. So I needed to give every single value a seperate class to seperate them.

Then I thought I put them in Arrays an loop them through with jQuery`.map()`, but now I'm stuck. I have no idea how I should continue wihtout wiriting a novel with the code...

Let me know if you need more code.

**Edit HTML Markup:**
Desktop Code example. Every row is build up the same.

```
<div class="js-notification-set--desk>
   {# Rechnung Row #}
        <div class="row">
            <fieldset>
                <legend class="col-sm-3">Rechnung</legend>

                {# Brief Radio #}
                <div class="mod-formelem col-sm-1">
                    <input type="radio" id="__radio1__" name="__row1__" class="js-notification-set--rechnung-brief" aria-labelledby="__sr01__"/>
                    <label for="__radio1__" class="mod-formelem--icon" aria-hidden="true"></label>
                </div>

                {# E-Mail Radio #}
                <div class="mod-formelem col-sm-1">
                    <input type="radio" id="__radio2__" name="__row1__" class="js-notification-set--rechnung-mail" checked="checked"
                           aria-labelledby="__sr02__"/>
                    <label for="__radio2__" class="mod-formelem--icon" aria-hidden="true"></label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
(...)
     </div>
```

Note: The `aria-labelledby` declares the label to each radio button. The buttons are in a table-like grid where the label stands at the top of the table. So there is no directed linked label.

Example for Mobile Select:

```
<div class="js-notification-set--mob">
   {# Rechnung Row #}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label for="___select1___" class="control-label">
                    Rechnung
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 js-tooltip--container">
                {# select1 #}
                <select data-select-type="default" data-placeholder="Rechnung"
                        class="form-control js-select js-notification-set--rechnung" name="Rechnung" id="___select1___">
                    <option value="___select1_option1___">Brief</option>
                    <option value="___select1_option2___" selected>E-Mail</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
(...)
</div>
```

Comment: share a sample html markup also

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Done. Hope that's enough.

Comment: Use the index of the radio button and then select the option with the same index in the corresponding select.

Comment: can you share the generated html instead of template

Comment: @ArunPJohny: It looks the same. The ID & Name won't be replaced since I don't connect the backend while developing. So the final HTML looks the same just with really ugly ID & name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the index of the radio button to select the corresponding option in the `<select>`.

```
$(".js-notification-set--desk :radio").click(function() {
    var index = $(".js-notification-set--desk :radio").index(this);
    $(".js-notification-set--rechnung").prop('selectedIndex', index);
});
```

Comment: I think that's the way to go. So `+1` & accept. Sadly it won't work for me because I just saw how messed up it looks when I attach the backend. So now it's a whole other story. But thank you. The I'll use the "core logic" of your answer.